# CSV translate data within rows

Tags: python, csv, translate, punctuation

i hope someone can point me in the right direction.

what would be an efficient way to translate data within a row[x]?

for example i want to convert the following: street,avenue,road,court to st,ave,rd,ct.

i was thinking of using a dictionary, the reason being is that sometimes the first letter will be capitalized and sometimes it wont ie: `{'ave':['Avenue','avenue','AVENUE','av','AV']}`

having said that, could i also do something (prior to translating) like convert all the data  to lower case (in the original csv file) to prevent working with data that contains mixed caps?

this is for csv files with anywhere between 500-1000 lines..
thank you

edit: i should add that the row[x] string would be something like: `'123 main street'` and that is what im looking to translate to `'123 main st'`

edit#2:

```
mydict = {'avenue':'ave', 'street':'st', 'road':'rd', 'court':'ct'}
add1 = '123 MAIN ROAD'
newadd1 = []

for i in add1.lower().split(' '):
    newtext = mydict.get(i.lower(),i)
    newadd1.append(newtext)

print ' '.join(newadd1)
```

thank you everyone

Comment: You can just call the lower() method the csv field. It is a  method common to string objects in python.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would tackle it would be, as you suggested, constructing a dictionary . For example, say that any form of Avenue - I would like to display as "Ave":

```
mapper = {'ave': 'Ave', 'avenue': 'Ave', 'av': 'Ave', 'st': 'Street', 'street': 'Street, ...}
```

and then use it with every word in the address field as follows:

```
word = mapper.get(word.lower(), word)
```

Comment: would this work when a row[] is equal to `'123 main avenue'` or would you have to do some type of `contains` method?

Comment: @jes516 for each word in `'123 main avenue'` I would run: `word = mapper.get(word.lower(), word)` and then `join` the result (on one space).

Comment: like this: add1 = `'123 MAIN STREET'` i would do: `for i in add1.split(' '):`

Comment: `for i in add1.split(' '):`     `word = mydict.get(i.lower(),i)`

Comment: if i wanted to create the above code (in my original question) into a function do i have to define the dictionary inside of the function? or can i define the dictionary outside of the function? i would like to create more functions like this which will require more dictionaries..

Comment: @jes516 it doesn't matter much if you define it inside or outside the function, unless you're going to make thousands of calls (or more) and in that case you'd better define it once outside the function instead of reconstructing it again and again.